# How to use System.PullRequest.SourceBranch in pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to configure a pipeline that authorizes the build only if the PR origin is from a specific branch.

For example, only authorize the build on main if the PR came from a 'release' or 'hotfix' branch.

I tried using the System.PullRequest.SourceBranch variable...

```
  - stage: release 
    displayName: Check_release_PR
    condition: eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release')
    jobs:  
    - job: check_pr
      steps:
      - bash:
         if [[ $(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch) == refs/heads/develop ]]; then
            echo "true"
         fi
```

```
stages: 
  - stage: main 
    displayName: "Check Main PR"
    condition: contains(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'bugfix' )
    jobs:  
    - job: check_pr
      steps:
      - bash: |
           echo true
```

```
stages: 
  - stage: main 
    displayName: "Check Main PR"
    condition: |
      and(
      eq(variables['build.sourceBranchName'], 'main'),
          or(
           startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/bugfix/'),
           startsWith(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/')
          )
      )
```

My git repo is on Azure

Comment: I found a similar issue on my company as well, the azure devops seems like lack of good example for the usage